# How to integral: $\int x^{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integral: $\int x^{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx$ ?

I try to use the rule: $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$, and

$u=x^{2}, du=2xdu, dv=e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx, v=-2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$, and

$\int x^{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx=x^{2}\cdot (-2e^{-\frac{x}{2}})-\int (-2e^{-\frac{x}{2}})2xdx$

However, it doesn't simplify anything.

Comment: That does simplify things. Integrate by parts again!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thanks,I have solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually simplify it. You reduce the order of the polynomial in the integral $\int x^k \cdot e^{x} dx$. (Integration by Parts is the general method to solve that). Apply it again on $\int x \cdot e^{\frac{-x}{2}} dx$ and you'll find out the answer. There also exists a method by using the Taylor expansion of exponential and turning the integral problem into a sum problem.

Comment: Thanks! I have performed another integration and solved it. But can you show me how to use the Taylor expansion? I once try to use gamma function, but the gamma function's integration is from 0 to positive infinity...

Comment: $exp(x) = \sum_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$ Therefore, $\int x^m e^x dx = \sum_k \int \frac{x^{m+k}}{k!} dx = \sum_k \frac{x^{m+k+1}}{(m+k+1)\cdot k!}_{Interval} $

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{d(x^ne^{mx})}{dx}=mx^ne^{mx}+nx^{n-1}e^{mx}$$

Integrate both sides to find $$x^ne^{mx}+k=nI_{n-1}+mI_n\implies I_n=?$$

where $\displaystyle I_n=\int x^ne^{mx}\ dx$

Here $n=2$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$\int x^{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx=x^{2}\cdot (-2e^{-\frac{x}{2}})-\int (-2e^{-\frac{x}{2}})2xdx=-2x^2\exp(-\frac{x}2)+4\int x\exp(-\frac{x}2)\, dx$$

Now, we just have to focus on $\int x \exp(-\frac{x}2)\, dx$.

Let $u=x, du=dx, dv=\exp(-\frac{x}2)\, dx,v=-2\exp(-\frac{x}2). $

After you perform another integration by part, you still have to integrate the exponential function one more time.

Comment: Thanks! I have performed another integration and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is $$\int_0^xt^2\exp -atdt=\partial_a^2\int_0^x\exp -atdt=\partial_a^2\frac{1-\exp -ax}{a}=\frac{2-(2+2ax+a^2x^2)\exp -ax}{a^3},$$which we can double-check by noting the above vanishes if $x=0$ and has $x$-derivative $x^2\exp -ax$ as required. Substiuting $a=\frac12$ gives $16-(16+8x+4x^2)\exp -x/2$. For an indefinite integral, just replace the first $16$ with $C$.